# Problem with "Calculated Formula" question in blackboard online test

Tags: technology-in-education, assessment, online-instruction

I received the error message "Question Syntax. There is an error in the syntax of this question. One or more variables may be invalid." when I tried to make the following question:

Compute $\|\langle [x], [y], [z] \rangle \times \langle [u], [v], [w] \rangle \|$.

The answer I entered was

$\sqrt{(y \times w - z \times v)^2 + (z \times u - x \times w)^2 + (x \times v - y \times u)^2}$.

Can anyone help me, please ?

EDIT: I am using the "blackboard learn" course management software. I am a teacher, making an online quiz for my students.

Comment: It is impossible to answer the question because the notation used in posing it is not defined.

Comment: The square brackets are required by the automatic answer calculation code in blackboard, to identify x, y, z, u, v and w as variables. I intended them to be real numbers. In the question, the automated system is not required to understand the mathematics, only to understand which are the variables. In the answer formula, I intend the 'x' symbol to mean multiplication of real numbers.

Comment: The angle brackets delimit vectors in $\mathbb{R}^3$ and the double vertical lines denote the norm, or magnitude.

Comment: Then your second formula includes squares of vector quantities, which are undefined, and your first includes vector products of scalar quantities, also undefined. The automated system certainly uses rules to enforce coherent use of notation.

Comment: Since y, w, z and v are real numbers, and since I intend the 'x' symbol in the answer to mean multiplication of real numbers, therefore the squares in the answer are squares of real numbers. Since, in the question, I intend the angle brackets to indicate vectors, and since the square brackets indicate to the code that their contents are variables, which I intend to be real numbers, therefore the cross in the question denotes vector product of vectors, not vector product of scalars, which, as you rightly say, would be undefined.

Comment: It is about the assessing of mathematics learning. Can you suggest an appropriate forum for my question, please ?

Comment: As I mentioned this is the blackboard website. I have searched at length in the available help files and fora. I had hoped this forum might be of use.

Comment: Blackboard is a course management tool used in many Universities: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blackboard_Learn. Those who are unfamiliar with it will of course be unable to answer my question. I had hoped that some users of this forum might have experience with it. Although you don't know it, in case there might be some users who do know it, I would ask that you please not vote to close my question. I am indeed a teacher trying to create a question, as I hoped I had conveyed by writing "...when I tried to make the following question...". Apologies if I was not clear.

Comment: I apologize that I misunderstood you.  I've retracted my close vote.  I suggest that you edit your post to include the details you've put as comments.

Comment: It's really disheartening to read the comments and realize the lack of reading and understanding skill,as well as knowledge, people commenting have. The notation used in the text question is irrelevant for blackboard. What blackboard asks is that you define variables in the text so that they can be substituted by values defined by the program when the student runs the quiz. It seems that blackboard programmers were unable to follow their own conventions...
[mod note: see below for continuation]

Comment: Just to make sure I am understanding the question:  is the X symbol you are using to denote multiplication of scalars the symbol that *Blackboard* wants you to use, or just one you are choosing here for clarity of presentation?

Comment: See my (new) comment on the OP.  Are you also using X for multiplication?  Could that possibly be the problem -- that Blackboard does not understand that symbol as an operator?

Comment: Thank you for your comment mweiss. I regret that I have forgotten the details because I moved on to a different system - see my comment on Dr. R's reply below.

Comment: Dr. R, Thank you very much for your very reassuring comments. The feedback was even harsher than you see here, before some posts were retracted by their posters ! I suspect that Socrates,  were he a Stack exchange member, would have the lowest reputation score among all members... In the end I gave up on the blackboard automated quizzes and used instead those of the publisher of the textbook, namely McGraw-Hill. These worked excellently.

Comment: [continued from converted answer by Dr. R, see above ] I have a similar error message when creating a formula question in blackboard, and I haven't being able to find a solution. The formula we're using are extremely simple, as they only involve the basic arithmetic operations and I can't get it to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the question was written using the Blackboard graphical formula editor, which cannot recognize the square brackets as variable definitions. For that you need to put the square-bracket variables in normal Blackboard text, not the formula editor. (Note the UI directions on the top of the screen: "Add *question text* that includes variables in square brackets [x] corresponding to variables in the formula that will be used to calculate the answer to this question.").

Having just tested it in Blackboard: The answer formula is fine. If I write the question using a Blackboard formula, then I get the same error as you. But if I instead write the question using basic text (like "Compute ||<[x], [y], [z]> x <[u], [v], [w]>||"), then that is accepted without the error. Obviously that text version isn't perfectly formatted, so you might need to play around with fonts or special characters to get it looking right.

Alternatively, you could write the question in natural language, as I think that feature is intended, i.e., "Find the norm when multiplying vectors <[x], [y], [z]> and <[u], [v], [w]>".